# Parse join query using Javascript pointer

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I have a two parse objects 'Content' and 'Detail'

Below I have added a screen shot of both classes in their data browsers.

[image: Content Class]   [image: Details Class]

I have a column in 'Content' called descId which is the Detail objects objectId and is a pointer to the 'Detail' Class.  I need to know how to obtain data from both classes.  This is my attempt but var Details is undefined.

```
var iBeacon = Parse.Object.extend('Details');
var content = Parse.Object.extend('Content');

var query = new Parse.Query(iBeacon);
query.include('descId');

query.find({
    success: function(results) {
//        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];

            var Details = object.get('Details');


            (function($) {
                $('#iBeaconTable').append('<tr><td id = "uuid" >' + object.get('uuid') + '</td><td = "proxId">' + object.get('proximity') + '</td><td = "offerId">' + object.get('offer') + '</td><td class = "buttonRow"><Button id = "btnEdit" onclick = "openDialog()" class = "flat-button">Edit</Button><Button id = "btnDelete" onclick = "Delete()" class = "flat-button">Delete</Button></td></tr>');//<Button id = "editSave">Save</Button></td></tr>');
            })(jQuery);
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

I am pulling my hair out on this and I really need dig out...regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are causing yourself confusion by naming the property on the `Content` class `descId`. The fact that Parse internally uses a pointer structure with an ID is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about, as far as your code is concerned you'll be using a full `Detail` object all the time.

The actual error in your code is this line:

```
var Details = object.get('Details');
```

Change it to:

```
// should be using the property name
var Details = object.get('descId');
```