# Backbone Parse pointer query - join table

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

Firstly I had gone through this [Parse join query using Javascript pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938154/parse-join-query-using-javascript-pointer) and its not working as they stated.

I would like to state what I want to achieve

Child Table

- pointer (parent) -> Parent Table

Parent Table

```
var query = new Parse.Query(ParentModel);
query.include('parent');
query.fetch({
    success: function(result){
         console.log(result.get('parent'));
    }
})
```

I'm getting **undefined** for this. 
First I would like to know whether this is achievable? Because I found that only 1 post stated this is possible and other is showing the other way round..

I have been stuck for few days for this. Please help out.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to retrieve multiple results?

Comment: yes, to be more specific. I wanna retrieve the child by querying the parent.

Comment: Could you show the structure of parent model?